# Fetching data using NSFetchedResultController

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm currently using NSFetchedResultController to work with a collectionView controller, I've read its different when using these two together in comparison to tableViews. I currently have core data that stores images based on the location. I have a button that deletes existing images displayed in the collectionView/Core Data and fetches new images. My images do not get deleted, it doubles each image and I'll have to leave that view controller and come back to see the fetched images.

```
 func setUpFetchedResultsViewController() {
           let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<FlickrImage> = FlickrImage.fetchRequest()
           let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "photo", ascending: true)
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "locations == %@", location)
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
           fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        fetchResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: dataController.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        
           fetchResultController.delegate = self
           do {
               try fetchResultController.performFetch()
           } catch {
               print(error.localizedDescription)
           }
        checkForImages()
    }


@objc func fetchNewItems() {
        let imagesInFlickr = fetchResultController.fetchedObjects!
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
           for image in imagesInFlickr {
            dataController.viewContext.delete(image)
            photoCollection.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
            try? dataController.viewContext.save()
           }
           //The function below downloads new images and saves into core data.
           downloadImageDetailsFromFlickr() 
           self.photoCollection.reloadData()
    }

func checkForImages() {
     if fetchResultController.fetchedObjects!.count == 0 {
        downloadImageDetailsFromFlickr()
        try? fetchResultController.performFetch()
        photoCollection.reloadData()
     } else {
        try? fetchResultController.performFetch()
        photoCollection.reloadData()
        }
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
           let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath) as! collectionCell
            let image = fetchResultController.object(at: indexPath)
                if let cellImage = image.photo {
                      DispatchQueue.main.async {
                           cell.imageView.image = UIImage(data: cellImage)
                      }
        }
        return cell
    }

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath) as! collectionCell
           
           if cell.isSelected {
               let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: .none, message: .none, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
               alertVC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
               alertVC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive, handler: { (_) in
                   let image = self.fetchResultController.object(at: indexPath)
                   self.dataController.viewContext.delete(image)
                do {
                   try self.dataController.viewContext.save()
                    try self.fetchResultController.performFetch()
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.photoCollection.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
                    self.photoCollection.reloadData()
                }
               }))
               present(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
           }
       }
```

Comment: Hmm... how does your cellForItemAt method look? Also, I assume that downloadImageDetailsFromFlickr downloads asynchronously? Shouldn't there be some sort of completion handler that reloads data _after_ download is completed?

Comment: @GabrielPires I did have a completion handler but it held up processes. My cellForItemAt is used to delete each item in the collection view when tapped.

Comment: Hmm so you removed the completion handler? For tap logic, you should be using "didSelectItemAtIndexPath" instead right?

Comment: @GabrielPires sorry I misinterpreted your first reply, I've edited my code. Both my cellForItemAt and DidSelectItemAt are included.

Comment: that's interesting. Instead of directly accessing `fetchResultController`... maybe it would be better to set up a simple object (maybe like a struct) and an array of that object that will hold the data you want to display. You could then update that array with the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods and call reloadData. (specifically, `didChangeObject`.)